# Performance testing SharePoint 2010

Tags: testing, performance

I'm eagerly awaiting the SharePoint 2010 Administrators toolkit to assist with performance testing.  We'd like to setup multiple configurations of hardware/topology to determine the best fit.   I'd like to use visual studio or another application to run load/stress/performance test against these different deployments to SharePoint 2010 to get some metrics back for comparison.

I'm interested in page load times (cached and non cached), search result times, RAM/CPU utilization.  I'm sure more metrics will pop up that we need too.

Has anyone attempted this?  Are there any helpful resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys!

I have successfully built a load test using Visual Studio 2010 Team Test.  I essentially created a test project, created 3 web performance tests (homepage response, performing a search on 3 different terms, and uploading a file).  I then created a load test in the same project which runs those performance tests as 25 users.  You can also configure the load test to report back the RAM, CPU, Disk IO, and any other WMI capable indicator of each server in the farm.  From what I understand you can also add some custom code to clean up files that you've uploaded, users created, etc...  I plan to blog about this on http://blog.fpweb.net soon.

I want to make the load test a little more dynamic as far as accepting host header inputs.  I'm also researching to see if it is possible to run these tests without Visual Studio in an automated fashion and report back the results somewhere.  If anyone has any information on that aspect please let me know.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: Can't find same post in your blog. Could you provide links please?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studion 2010 Team Suite - test edition is definitely the way to go.

I created custom code to create a site collection with a deep enough page hierarchy and enough documents to produce a 2GB website automatically. That was more work than creating the load tests to actually load it.

Using a load test agent and controller to generate more load requires a separate license and certain shortcuts you might use in Visual Studio (e.g. hardcoding filenames for upload) will create issues.

The biggest issue I had was upload documents with a random url so that subsequent runs on the load test would not clash with the files. Adding a guid to the end of the page name worked okay, but simulating web document upload was harder.

At the end of the day, being able to prove that the server configuration was going to handle the load required of it is a huge bonus when considering the $$ that go toward making a SharePoint site a success.

Comment: Thanks Nat!  I was able to make the load test a little more dynamic for accepting site URLs and usernames from a config file.  I'm going to look into figuring out how to use power shell to truncate a doc lib (delete all documents) before the next run of the load test. I may need to write a cmdlet.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Be easier to take a database backup of the content DB and restore it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested perf against 2010 myself, however if you have Visual Studio Team System, you can use the functionality within that product. It's only page response time (I think) but that's a guide and you could see what impact changing server roles has. Here's an [article to explain it by Amit Chatterjee](http://blogs.msdn.com/amit%5Fchatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx).

I'm certain there must be free/open source tools out there as well that hopefully people can suggest?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did end up using VSTS 2010 to create a load test.  See below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you are looking for, but it's somewhat related. For performance testing of **code**, the Developer Dashboard helps you with indentifying bottlenecks.

Also check out [SharePoint 2010 Developer Dashboard Visualizer](http://devdashvis.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Given the extra cost associated with performance testing with VS: Anyone tried testing a Sharepoint 2010 site with OpenSTA, Grinder, JMeter or other free performance testing tool?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with JMeter and it gives comparable results for page download time, Search and for most of the performance transactions that we are planning to do with Sharepoint 2010